# How to Implement 301 Redirects with Django/Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm looking to redirect a list of old URLs to a list of new URLs in a Django/Heroku app.

Since I'm using Heroku, I can't just use an `.htaccess` file.

I see that rails has rack-rewrite, but I haven't seen anything like that for Django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django has redirects app, which allows to store redirects list in database:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/

Also here a generic RedirectView:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#redirectview

And the lowest level is HttpResponseRedirect:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: The redirects app is exactly what I needed.  It'll work for a list of apps, and seems to be much cleaner than adding everything to my urls conf. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use redirect. Please check below code.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect(
                '/', permanent=True
            )
```

It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [redirect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to)

Example from the docs for a 301 redirect:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    ('^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/bar/%(id)s/'}),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the [redirects app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/) mentioned in the accepted answer is a pretty nice solution, it also involves a database call for every 404 error.  I wanted to avoid this so ended up just manually implementing this in a URL conf.

```py
"""redirects.py that gets included by urls.py"""
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


def redirect_view(slug):
    """
    Helper view function specifically for the redirects below since they take
    a kwarg slug as an argument.
    """
    return RedirectView.as_view(
        url=reverse_lazy('app_name:pattern_name', kwargs={'slug': slug}),
        permanent=True)

urlpatterns = [
    path('example-redirect/', redirect_view('new-url')),
]
```